# Add Keychain and computer crash

Tags: icloud, keychain

I'm trying to understand how Apple Keychain works. If I understand correctly, only passwords that are in the iCloud Keychain will be shared with my other devices and saved if I lose the computer. Is that correct?
(I mean the passwords in Keychain program top left Keychains > iCloud)

I can create other Keychains: File > Add Keychain. If the computer with that new keychain crashes or is stolen, everything in that new keychain will be lost. Is that correct? Is there anyway to solve that? Is there any way to put that new keychain in iCloud?

Comment: That's what backups are for.

Comment: @Tetsujin: how to backup a keychain, then

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-7081 - or just use Time Machine